# git subtree cache exists

Tags: git, git-subtree, subtree

I started to using subtree but ended in mess now. Googling and the man page didn't help that I can find out how to solve this error. Anyone an idea?

- Repo: https://github.com/Azd325/gitkraken
- OS: macOS 11.5.1
- git: git version 2.32.0

Error:

```
➜ git subtree split -P gitkraken --rejoin
cache for 12d7b0ee9414ebd0414070d22fb40db7446badd9 already exists!
```

Example to reproduce it, externally.

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
touch readme.md
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git add readme.md
git commit -m "add readme"
git subtree add --prefix gitkraken "aur@aur.archlinux.org:gitkraken.git" master
git subtree split -P "gitkraken" --rejoin
```

Currently, in my repo I switched the folder to `gitkraken-aur` and so it works for the moment again.

Attempt from the first answer to remove the subtree folder.

```
test on  main [?]
➜ rm -rf .git/subtree-cache

test on  main [?]
➜ git subtree split -P "gitkraken" --rejoin

cache for 12d7b0ee9414ebd0414070d22fb40db7446badd9 already exists!

test on  main [?]
➜ git subtree pull -P gitkraken "aur@aur.archlinux.org:gitkraken.git" master -m "Merge subbtree gitkraken"
From aur.archlinux.org:gitkraken
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

test on  main [?]
➜ git subtree push -P gitkraken "aur@aur.archlinux.org:gitkraken.git" master
git push using:  aur@aur.archlinux.org:gitkraken.git master
cache for 12d7b0ee9414ebd0414070d22fb40db7446badd9 already exists!

test on  main [?]
➜ rm -rf .git/subtree-cache

test on  main [?]
➜ git subtree push -P gitkraken "aur@aur.archlinux.org:gitkraken.git" master
git push using:  aur@aur.archlinux.org:gitkraken.git master
cache for 12d7b0ee9414ebd0414070d22fb40db7446badd9 already exists!
```

More debug information to attempt one.

```
test on  main [?]
➜ rm -rf .git/subtree-cache

test on  main [?]
➜ tree .git
.git
├── COMMIT_EDITMSG
├── FETCH_HEAD
├── HEAD
├── ORIG_HEAD
├── branches
├── config
├── description
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── pre-merge-commit.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── pre-receive.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   ├── push-to-checkout.sample
│   └── update.sample
├── index
├── info
│   └── exclude
├── logs
│   ├── HEAD
│   └── refs
│       └── heads
│           └── main
├── objects
│   ├── 0c
│   │   └── ce20ac9c41edfaafd245059b066f4e644b6c84
│   ├── 23
│   │   └── 9ec593c6a2192e76c005435f748b2ad28be832
│   ├── 69
│   │   └── 3d7dd0cbe326ad51fffad7408c2c6cc8af7e0d
│   ├── 74
│   │   └── 11ec84b161eba98f6ae09d2210c231393c977c
│   ├── 84
│   │   └── a5dcf23e618a493da589f95f2c57da22603e2a
│   ├── 99
│   │   └── 03d6d6b962b96143f3e2c0b75550561de14c06
│   ├── b3
│   │   └── 5caa9cbb57f55fb05260b3dd767f92c62a20ba
│   ├── bf
│   │   └── 52649a7b94057b0da0a7f1bb20c55b395717be
│   ├── e4
│   │   └── 22b2b19b0c80773ccbad0822130158a024ef59
│   ├── e6
│   │   └── 9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
│   ├── eb
│   │   └── 4c7f2ebf6596f7e3c40b2355bc11e7a1badf58
│   ├── info
│   └── pack
│       ├── pack-542055b17c2fb18100e23d143d0f824b0c5ee19f.idx
│       └── pack-542055b17c2fb18100e23d143d0f824b0c5ee19f.pack
└── refs
    ├── heads
    │   └── main
    └── tags

23 directories, 37 files

test on  main [?]
➜ git subtree split -P "gitkraken" --rejoin

cache for 12d7b0ee9414ebd0414070d22fb40db7446badd9 already exists!

test on  main [?]
➜ tree .git
.git
├── COMMIT_EDITMSG
├── FETCH_HEAD
├── HEAD
├── ORIG_HEAD
├── branches
├── config
├── description
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── pre-merge-commit.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── pre-receive.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   ├── push-to-checkout.sample
│   └── update.sample
├── index
├── info
│   └── exclude
├── logs
│   ├── HEAD
│   └── refs
│       └── heads
│           └── main
├── objects
│   ├── 0c
│   │   └── ce20ac9c41edfaafd245059b066f4e644b6c84
│   ├── 23
│   │   └── 9ec593c6a2192e76c005435f748b2ad28be832
│   ├── 69
│   │   └── 3d7dd0cbe326ad51fffad7408c2c6cc8af7e0d
│   ├── 74
│   │   └── 11ec84b161eba98f6ae09d2210c231393c977c
│   ├── 84
│   │   └── a5dcf23e618a493da589f95f2c57da22603e2a
│   ├── 99
│   │   └── 03d6d6b962b96143f3e2c0b75550561de14c06
│   ├── b3
│   │   └── 5caa9cbb57f55fb05260b3dd767f92c62a20ba
│   ├── bf
│   │   └── 52649a7b94057b0da0a7f1bb20c55b395717be
│   ├── e4
│   │   └── 22b2b19b0c80773ccbad0822130158a024ef59
│   ├── e6
│   │   └── 9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
│   ├── eb
│   │   └── 4c7f2ebf6596f7e3c40b2355bc11e7a1badf58
│   ├── info
│   └── pack
│       ├── pack-542055b17c2fb18100e23d143d0f824b0c5ee19f.idx
│       └── pack-542055b17c2fb18100e23d143d0f824b0c5ee19f.pack
├── refs
│   ├── heads
│   │   └── main
│   └── tags
└── subtree-cache
    └── 24098
        ├── 12d7b0ee9414ebd0414070d22fb40db7446badd9
        ├── 9903d6d6b962b96143f3e2c0b75550561de14c06
        ├── e9aad069b8e1e49f8cbb54cb91e3f226e4949712
        └── notree

26 directories, 40 files
```

Comment: Can you give a link to the repository you are trying to split? And on which commit are you executing this?

Comment: What OS and git version are you using?

Comment: Add more infoss

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the subtree cache by removing the `.git/subtree-cache` folder. You could always try seaching for the `12d7b0ee9414ebd0414070d22fb40db7446badd9` file inside that folder and remove just that.

And then try again again executing your command.

I was able to reproduce and fix that way, the answer was found by reverse engineering the code causing the error : https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh#L329

Comment: I removed the folder, but still the cache issue appears.

Comment: @Azd325 could you remove the folder *manually*? Not using the command line?

Comment: I added how I did it in the question above. I used `rm -rf .git/subtree-cache`

Comment: Can you debug please? It's hard seeing the problem without additional info. Delete the folder, go to your file explorer, check that it doesn't exist, run your command and check the folders/files that it creates

Comment: I added a overview of the files which are created.

Comment: Hm, running into the same issue, and clearing out `.git/subtree-cache` also did not help (it just gets recreated). @Azd325, did you wind up finding a fix for this?

Comment: No, didn't find one, still sticking to my workaround with a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent many times to solving it.

My co-worker had same problem and after reinstalling git several times, it was solved and I asked him which version he was using.

After downgrading the git version to 2.30.2,
'cache for *** exist' message still appears, but 'subtree push' operation worked successfully

The git version with the problem in my case was 2.35.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help in debugging this issue, but I am still getting it today with git version 2.39.2.

The way I got to this point was probably by adding git subtrees, then removing them sometime after to re-add the same ones again. I was testing with a monorepo repository.

My feeling is that if somewhere in the history there have been more than one subtree add, this happens:

```
git subtree push -d --prefix commerce/packages/xx/xx-component-phpmd-config xx-component-phpmd-config main

command: {push}
quiet: {}
dir: {commerce/packages/xx/xx-component-phpmd-config}
opts: {xx-component-phpmd-config main}

git push using:  xx-component-phpmd-config main
Splitting commerce/packages/xx/xx-component-phpmd-config...
Using cachedir: /Users/antonevers/web/xx/xx-monorepo/.git/subtree-cache/12575
Looking for prior splits...
  Main is: '5cc22cd76dc2ddd4fdaf05445ebee23c4705eee1'
    Prior: 5cc22cd76dc2ddd4fdaf05445ebee23c4705eee1 -> ede24f61adf6ce0b1a7853c334470a88f27c7bef
  Main is: '2b41e165071909200abd959fc609aea4c97bcd82'
    Prior: 2b41e165071909200abd959fc609aea4c97bcd82 -> ede24f61adf6ce0b1a7853c334470a88f27c7bef
fatal: cache for ede24f61adf6ce0b1a7853c334470a88f27c7bef already exists!
```

I have solved the issue by branching off from a part in the history before first adding subtrees. Then started over completely. Thus bypassing the point in history where subtrees have been added to the same path more than once.